# Can not use ffmpeg to convert a flv file into mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flv

I have a flv file, which can be played normally with potplayer, but it cannot be converted into mp4 format with ffmpeg. File: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ukexdhw15tyfrcx/2.22_xindongfang.flv/file

I typed `ffmpeg -i 2.22_xindongfang.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy test.mp4`, and the following error log appeared:

```
[mp4 @ 0000018bbe928880] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

Comment: Try as: `ffmpeg -i "2.22_xindongfang.flv" -c copy test.mp4`. Let me know if it works and I'll explain the why. Otherwise I'll test your file after downloading.

Comment: @VC.One still failed

Comment: It's right, it's an unsupported codec; VLC doesn't read your file, and ffprobe shows errors. Which codec has created the file?

Comment: @pierpy From the network packet capture for live broadcast